# I deleted /bin/rm. How do I recover it?

Tags: command-line, rm, dpkg

Just for fun, I thought I would use this command on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian:

```
sudo rm -f /bin/rm
```

I thought I could just reinstall `coreutils`: I was wrong!

`apt-get install --reinstall coreutils` gives an error from `dpkg`, saying it couldn't remove the package. Compiling from source doesn't work because the `Makefile` uses `rm`.

How can I get a working `rm` back?

Comment: Every .deb is basically an archive you can unpack and simply copy the rm executable to /bin.

Comment: What OS is this? Linux? Unix? Something else? If Linux, which distro? 64bit? 32?

Comment: Linux raspbian on raspberry pi 512mb. Don't know if 64 or 32 bit.

Comment: `ln -s /usr/lib/initramfs-tools/bin/busybox /bin/rm` (or `/bin/busybox`, or extract it from an initrd)

Comment: The Raspberry Pi has its OS on an SD memory card so you can just extract the rm binary from the package on another machine and copy it back onto the card. In any case, hilarious stunt you pulled there and very bold of you to admit it publicly :)

Comment: At least this isn't as bad as the time I did `sudo chown -R /` . System started doing all sorts of unexpected things and eventually I gave up trying to undo the damage and just wiped the drive.

Comment: Wow, 37 people had this same question?

Comment: @user645715 37 people found this question amusing.

Comment: +1 for experimentation!  So, was it fun? :P

Comment: I suppose that at this point suggesting `cd /; rm -r -f` would be considered piling on..?

Comment: +1 for making me laugh!
@BobJarvis: why not `rm -rf /*` to sail safe while saving precious bytes?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

```
sudo touch /bin/rm && sudo chmod +x /bin/rm
apt-get download coreutils
sudo dpkg --unpack coreutils*
```

And never again.

---

> Why didn't you use sudo with apt-get?

Because the `download` command doesn't require it:

> `download`
>              download will download the given binary package into the **current
>              directory.**

So, unless you are in some directory you can't write, you don't need to use `sudo`, and it could get problematic later on since you will need `root` permissions to remove/move the package.

Comment: apt-get needs to be run with sudo :)

Comment: @AWippler no, in this case no.

Comment: Note that an empty executable file is executed as a shell script that does nothing. So that means invoking `/bin/sh`. It would have been simpler to do a `sudo ln -s true /bin/rm` or even better `sudo ln -s busybox /bin/rm` to have a working `rm`.

Comment: `apt-get` does need sudo if you haven't downloaded coreutils because otherwise it won't be able to write to `/var` where debian saves the downloaded files.

Comment: @KristopherIves wrong... `apt-get` downloads the package to the current directory *always* (yeah, even if you used `sudo`), so unless you are in a directory you can't write as your user you don't need `sudo`. Please check the man pages.

Answer (score 108):

Debian and its derivatives (and probably most other distributions) come with [`busybox`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) which is used in the `initramfs`.

`busybox` bundles most core command line utilities in a single executable.

You can temporarily symlink `/bin/rm` to `/bin/busybox`:

```
ln -s busybox /bin/rm
```

To get a working `rm` (after which you can do your `apt-get install --reinstall coreutils`).

That same method can be used for all the other utilities that `busybox` includes. That list varies from one deployment to another. You can get the list with `busybox --list`.

Note however that they are limited versions of the corresponding utilities. They sometimes support GNU extensions, but generally not and some of them will not even support all the standard/POSIX features (some features can be enabled/disabled at compile time).

Alternatively, you could use `zsh`'s builtin rm:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/files
rm "$@"
```

The `zsh/files` module provides with a few additional builtin commands (`rm`, `mv`, `ln`, `mkdir`, `rmdir`, `chown`, `chmod`, `sync`). It's useful in this kind of situation or when you cannot fork more processes but do have an interactive `zsh` running.

`ksh93` also has a number of extra/optional commands buitin, but not `rm` among them (`basename`, `chmod`, `dirname`, `getconf`, `head`, `mkdir`, `logname`, `cat`, `cmp`, `cut`, `uname`, `wc`, `sync`). You can invoke them with:

```
command /opt/ast/bin/the-command
```

in a `ksh93` script or invoke `builtin the-command` for the `the-command` builtin to be enabled and replace the external one.

Comment: Great answer.  Makes me wonder if the OP really needs to reinstall the real `rm` at all.  ;-)

Comment: Indeed. Actually, this makes me think about deleting coreutils too... :-)

Comment: @Damon: coreutils provide a extended version of the basic commands compared to busybox, so while busybox might be enough to match SUSv3 requirements, coreutils are more featureful; for example busybox has limited i18n support.

Comment: @liori: I was half-joking, though 10-15 years ago, I would probably indeed have done it in that situation (the added "features", _in particular i18n_, are not an advantage in my opinion -- unintellegible translations, and learning to use switches that unexpectedly break scripts on another computer, no thanks). However, nowadays, I'm happy if only a Linux system runs smoothly as-installed without me touching anything, and without having to move/delete/edit system/config files or binaries. Which sadly, still isn't the case often enough, so I'm surely not touching _something that works_ :-)

Answer (score 30):

In case `apt-get` or `dpkg` needs `rm` and without `rm` a reinstallation is not posssible, then you can emulate `rm` with `perl`:

```
cat > /bin/rm << "EOF"
#!/usr/bin/perl
foreach (@ARGV) { unlink $_ or warn "$@:$!"; }
EOF
chmod +x /bin/rm
```

Comment: Note that it doesn't handle `-r`, and the fact that it doesn't return a correct exit status may cause problems.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas it is sufficient to allow `apt-get install --reinstall coreutils` and get the OP back to normal.

Comment: that's why I wrote "in case". the package coreutils has no scripts. typically the pre- and post-install scripts fail on errors if files are exists or don't exist, for example if they need to be removed. And yes, it is true I was too lazy to check the package in advance.

Comment: you could also emulate `rm` with `mv` (to 'trash bin')

Answer (score 14):

I would try obtaining the correct `rm` binary from another machine, and then using `scp` or something to copy it to the Pi. This of course only works if `scp` is already installed...

If `scp` is not available, then `nc` (a.k.a. netcat) on the sending side and bash with a `/dev/tcp/HOST/PORT` redirection on the receiving side might work as well.

If you don't have another Raspbian machine, you can retrieve the [coreutils package](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/c/coreutils/) (get the `.deb` for the right version), and unpack it with `dpkg-deb` (on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/…, even if it isn't on a Pi):

```
dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile coreutils*.deb | tar xf - ./bin/rm
```

If you don't have another machine with dpkg, you can extract the file with `ar` (from the binutils development tools) and tar:

```
ar p coreutils*.deb data.tar.gz  | tar xzf - ./bin/rm
```

Comment: If `scp` is not available, then `nc` (a.k.a. `netcat`) on the sending side and `bash` with a `/dev/tcp/HOST/PORT` redirection on the receiving side might work as well.

Answer (score 13):

Since it's debian (or ubuntu), there's an easy way to get the files:

```
mkdir /tmp/coreutils
sudo dpkg-deb --extract /var/cache/apt/archives/coreutils_ [tab complete for correct version].deb /tmp/coreutils
sudo cp /tmp/coreutils/bin/rm /bin
```

This works because apt-get downloaded the coreutils.deb before trying to install it, and dpkg-deb guaranteed to exist on a debian-based system.

Don't extract directly to /tmp, it changes permissions on the parent directory.

If you're going to play around, you may want to install the package busybox-static, which works even if you break everything else.