# I have removed 'head' manually - how do I reinstall it?

Tags: ubuntu, head

It seems that I've removed **head** manually from my `/usr/bin/`
a couple of months ago. Now that I chance to need it I don't have it.
How do I reinstall it without reinstalling the whole distro?
My environment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop.

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115743/i-deleted-bin-rm-how-do-i-recover-it/115744 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238475/reinstall-env-program

Comment: @muru Thanks for the links, the solutions in them were relevant to my problem as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can re-install `head` by re-installing the package which contains it; from a terminal window, run

```
sudo apt reinstall coreutils
```

(In older versions of `apt`, pre-1.8.0~rc1, run `sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils` instead.)

You can determine which package is involved by running

```
dpkg -S bin/head
```

Comment: I was going to suggest https://packages.ubuntu.com/ as another option. However, for some reason, the "packages that contain files named like this" search doesn't find anything with the keyword "/usr/bin/head", but gives exactly that file if I search for "/bin/head" instead... (??)

Comment: @ilkkachu right, files are moving around with the `/usr` merge, it’s safer to look for `bin/head`.